# if-else condition for multiple data files repeats output

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, rstudio

i'd appreciate your help on something that is currently driving me crazy.
I'm processing some data regarding different characteristics with a loop & everything besides this particular function is working properly:

```
fun<-function(X)
   {
     Y <- numeric()
     if(max(X)== X[1]){Y<-0}else{Y=X[which.max(X)-1]}
   return(Y)
  }
```

so:
say, I got 5 different csv.-files in my directory, which i'm refering to. in a certain row there are values, which im comparing with the expression 
`X[which.max(X)-1]`

So for instance I have got 3 values in my file:

```
3.5;6.4;7.1  -> the function should give me 6.4
2.8;1.6;2.3  -> the function should give me 0
```

... and so on.

The function itself is working, but for 5 different files I always get the same output-value. In this case I would get five time 6.4 . So it just repeats the very first output and does not actually consider the values of the second file.

I hope i explained my problem accurate and would appreciate hints and suggestions :)

the entire code:

```
setwd("C:\\Users")

data = list.files(pattern="*.csv", full.names= TRUE)
data
t = length(data)


    output= data.frame(Output1=NA)
    for (i in 1:t) {

      Characteristics <- read.csv(file=data[i], sep=";", nrows = 22)

      Duration = as.character (Characteristics [8,1])
      Duration = as.numeric(strsplit(Duration," ") [[1]][4])

      X = as.character(Characteristics [9:(8+Duration),1])
      X = as.numeric (X)

      fun<-function(X)
       {
         Y <- numeric()
         if(max(X)== X[1]){Y<-0}else{Y <- X[which.max(X)-1]}
       return(Y)
      }


      Output1 = Y

    output [i,1] <- Output1
    }
```

cheers,
Olli

Comment: How are you reading values from file and passing it to function? Please share that part of code as well

Comment: No taglines please.

Comment: @Olli Where are you using function `fun`? Why it has been defined inside for-loop?

Comment: @MKR, i'm sorry I adjusted that, so "bla" is is actually "fun". 
should I define the function outside of the loop? What difference does that make?

If I do so, how do I make sure that Y is computed for all my files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fun` has not been used properly in code. First of all, the purpose of the `fun` is not very clear and its not assigning any value to `Y` either. If purpose of the `fun` is to to find max value in `X` and  assign index of it to `Y`. Then best option could be define the function separately.

```
     # define fun as separate 
      fun <- function(X)
       {
         Y <- numeric()
         if(max(X)== X[1]){Y<-0}else{Y <- X[which.max(X)-1]}
       return(Y)
      }

 #Modify for-loop as
 for (i in 1:t) { 
   Characteristics <- read.csv(file=data[i], sep=";", nrows = 22) 
   Duration = as.character (Characteristics [8,1]) 
   Duration = as.numeric(strsplit(Duration," ") [[1]][4]) 
   X = as.character(P_Char [9:(8+Duration),1]) 
   X = as.numeric (X) 

   Output1 = fun(x) 
   output [i,1] <- Output1 
}
```